# Find the distance of the centroid of the triangle ABC from the origin?

Tags: geometry

A sphere of radius $r$ passes through the origin and the other points where it meets the coordinate axes are A, B and C. Find the distance of the centroid of the triangle ABC from the origin (in terms of $r$).

i was taking the coordinate of the centroid ($\frac{x+y+z}{3}$,  $\frac{X+Y+Z}{3}$).   but   i  don't know the distance  of the centroid  of triangle ABC  from the origin. From my point of view  i was using the distance formula  from the origin,, but i didn't get it

if anybody help me me  i would be very thankful to him
thank you

Comment: Are we in two or three dimensions ? I guess in two ; a point with coordinates $(u,v)$ has distance $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ from the origin. In three dimensions, it is not much harder : The distcnae of a point with coordinates $(u,v,w)$ from the origin is $\sqrt{u^2+v^2+w^2}$

Comment: You considered that entering something like $5+4+7/3$ into a calculator does not give the correct result $(5+4+7)/3$ , didn't you ?

Answer (score 1):

If the sphere intersects the three axes at the points A, B and C, it means that the sphere passes through these three points:

$(A,0,0)$; $(0,B,0)$; $(0,0,C)$

i.e., the sphere intersects x-axis at $(A,0,0)$ and y-axis at $(0,B,0)$ and z-axis at $(0,0,C)$

Now, coordinates of the centroid of triangle formed by these three co-ordinates will be:

$(\frac{A+0+0}{3},\frac{0+B+0}{3},\frac{0+0+C}{3})$ = $(\frac{A}{3},\frac{B}{3},\frac{C}{3})$

To find distance of this centroid from origin $(0,0,0)$ we simply use the two point distance formula in 3d:

Distance between $(\frac{A}{3},\frac{B}{3},\frac{C}{3})$ and $(0,0,0)$ =

$\sqrt{(\frac{A}{3}-0)^2 + (\frac{B}{3}-0)^2 + (\frac{C}{3}-0)^2}$ = $\frac{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2}}{3}$

---

In our case, the radius of sphere is given as $r$.

Let's assume the centre of sphere to be at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. Then the equation of the sphere can be written as:

$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2 = r^2$

Since it's also given that the sphere passes through the origin $(0,0,0)$, this point must satisfy the above equation of sphere.

Or, $(0-x_0)^2+(0-y_0)^2+(0-z_0)^2 = r^2$

Or, $x_0^2 + y_0^2 + z_0^2 = r^2$    --- $(1)$

Now, the sphere also passes through the point $(A,0,0)$. Substituting this point in the equation of sphere, we have:

$(A-x_0)^2+(0-y_0)^2+(0-z_0)^2 = r^2$

Or, $(A-x_0)^2+y_0^2+z_0^2 = r^2$

From $(1)$, let's also substitute $r^2$ with $x_0^2 + y_0^2 + z_0^2$

$(A-x_0)^2+y_0^2+z_0^2 = x_0^2 + y_0^2 + z_0^2$

Or, $(A-x_0)^2 = x_0^2$

Or, $A-x_0 = x_0$

Thus we have $A = 2x_0$.

Similarly by substituting $(0,B,0)$ and $(0,0,C)$ in the equation of sphere we get $B = 2y_0$ and $C= 2z_0$.

Hence, the three points A, B and C are $(2x_0,0,0)$, $(0,2y_0,0)$ and $(0,0,2z_0)$ respectively.

Thus, by using the formula we arrived at in section 1, we can say the distance of centroid of triangle ABC from origin =

$\frac{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2}}{3}$ = $\frac{\sqrt{(2x_0)^2 + (2y_0)^2 + (2z_0)^2}}{3}$ = $\frac{2\sqrt{x_0^2 + y_0^2 + z_0^2}}{3}$

But from equation $(1)$ we know that $x_0^2 + y_0^2 + z_0^2 = r^2$.

Substituting this we have the required distance as $\frac{2\sqrt{r^2}}{3} = \frac{2r}{3}$

Comment: What is $(A,0,0)$ and the others ?, they shall be $(R,0,0)$ etc. (it,s a sphere not an ellipsoid)! the remaining is ok

Comment: @GCab you're confused. The centre of sphere is not the origin. The sphere is passing through the origin. So the three points A, B and C will be at distances a, b and c respectively. None of a, b or c necessarily need be equal to R. I assumed the three distances as A, B and C (since it's not clear in the question whether they're just the labels or distances). Ellipsoid/sphere is irrelevant here. We can also replace A, B, C with X, Y, Z respectively..

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, I misunderstood the sphere as centered at the origin.

Comment: thanks a lot @ yathish  but  my teacher said that  answer is  2r/3,, i don't how 2r/3 comes..........

Comment: @legohlegoh can you please share the exact question that your teacher asked you?

Comment: A sphere of radius r passes through the origin and the other points
where it meets the coordinate axes are A, B and C. Find the distance of the
centroid of the triangle ABC from the origin.,,,this the exact question

Comment: @legohlegoh yes, in this case answer was be 2r/3. My solution needs to be updated. I'll be able to update the answer in some hours since I don't have access to computer right now (for formatting).

Comment: thanks@ yathish,,,ok im waiting for u

Comment: @legohlegoh I've just updated the solution. Please don't be overwhelmed by the length. I've taken the liberty of being very elaborate. But once you understand the solution, you will be able to write it in a very concise manner :)

Comment: thanks a lot  and love u@yathish

Comment: @legohlegoh you're welcome! If my answer was helpful, kindly mark it as accepted answer..